# Xamarin forms iCloud drive delete an item

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am developing a Xamarin forms application.User can save images from the app to iCloud.Is it possible to delete a document by it's name in the iCloud drive from an app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be possible according to [Apples Documentation on iCloud API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546573/xamarin-forms-icloud-drive-delete-an-item) on iOS only.

See [Xamarin's introduction to developing with iCloud on iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_icloud/). Note that this will only work with iOS since the API is designed around the Mac and iOS APIs. Since you said this is a Forms application, you will have to figure something else out for the other platforms. There are many options and that is up to you to decide (OneDrive, Google Drive, DropBox etc.).

Disclaimer: I work for Xamarin/Microsoft